# JavaFX 8 make desktop screenshot

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am developing JavaFX 8 (with Java 8) application, and I need to make the entire desktop screenshot by button click. I can't find doc how to use it. Please give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
public void saveAsPng() {
    WritableImage image = barChart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);

    // TODO: probably use a file chooser here
    File file = new File("chart.png");

    try {
        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception here
    }
}
```

or go through [This OFFICIAL tutorial to take a snapshot using JavaFX](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/take_a_snaphot_with_javafx)
or [Tutorial to work it using Robots](http://java-buddy.blogspot.in/2016/01/capture-screen-using-javaawtrobot.html)

Comment: @avalon for the entire desktop, check the last tutorial link. Posted here again [Click here to access](http://java-buddy.blogspot.in/2016/01/capture-screen-using-javaawtrobot.html)